# Compile and wrap markdown with a jade layout

Tags: pug, markdown, static-site

I have several folders (a book) with markdown files which I'd like to compile to HTML with a Jade layout — *without* changing my markdown files to jade and specifying the layout in every file.

I have this:

```
# This is my article

Compile me.
```

I want to generate this:

```
extends layout

block outlet
:markdown
    # This is my article

    Compile me.
```

… and then compile it. I can prepend the first part to the files using something like [gulp-insert](https://github.com/rschmukler/gulp-insert) but the markdown file needs to be indented inside the :markdown filter. So Jade might not be the best suit.

Any ideas how to solve this? Or a better idea?

Comment: Have you considered a script which appends the indentation to each line? You could split into lines, loop through them, inserting white-space in each, then join the lines and write back to file. Or you could do a search and replace: replace all `\n` with `\n\t` -- just don't forget to account for first and last lines. After doing that, then insert front matter. Not sure which language you would be using.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution. Will try that. Mind leaving an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The jade reference gives an example of [including filtered text](http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/); see the appropriate section there.

Adapted to your example, it could look like this:

```
extends layout

block outlet
include:markdown article.md
```

Comment: Haven't run the example. But if it works, you might be able to generate the jade files by inserting the markdown-file names automatically. Or even use variables and javascript within jade? Would love to hear if that's possible.